Вопрос по ООП, экземпляр моего класса, при его создании и добавлении в дерево должен являться сценой (композицией нод), а не одной нодой
Как сделать так, чтобы экземпляр моего класса, при его создании и добавлении в дерево являлся сценой (композицией нод), а не одной нодой. (моя реализация кажется мне слишком костыльной)
То-есть проблема моей первой реализации состоит в том, что я создаю объект класса через var entity = Entity.new(аргументы для _init()), он успешно создаётся в памяти, весь скрипт срабатывает, а потом я добавляю этот объект в дерево add_child(entity) - он создаёт ноду CharacterBody2D, которую расширяет мой класс, а тк она не является Entity.gd - то не имеет его функционала (такая реализация бесполезна, ибо я просто создаю в памяти нужный мне объект, а в дереве появляется жопа)
Тогда я решил сделать опять же var entity = Entity.new(аргументы для _init()), он успешно создаётся в памяти, весь скрипт срабатывает, а потом я добавляю этот объект в дерево add_child(entity.preloaded_scene.instantiate() #preloaded_scene - это preload("res://scenes/entity.tscn"), такая реализация работает, но проблема в том, что я получаю в памяти два объекта entity, а в дерево добавляется только второй. Я хз как я написал этот костыль, но дубликат возникает из-за того, что когда я подгружаю сцену, корневой нодой которой является нода типа Entity.gd а при её добавлении в памяти создаётся ещё один объект Entity.gd, который уже и указывает на визуализированную сцену в дереве, в то время как изначальный объект теряется в памяти. (вот пока что такая у меня реализация, буду рад, если кто-то подскажет как мне убрать это лишнее звено в виде изначального объекта)
Возможно все проблемы в моей реализации класса Entity.gd:
extends CharacterBody2D
class_name Entity

var preloaded_scene = preload("res://scenes/entity.tscn")

var _name: String
var speed: float
var hp: int
var max_hp: int
var label; var label_hp; var collision

func _ready():
    print("сцена добавлена в дерево")
    label = $Label
    label_hp = $Label_hp
    collision = $CollisionShape2D
    label.text=_name
    label_hp.text="{cur_hp} / {max_hp}".format({"cur_hp": hp, "max_hp": max_hp})

func _init(_name_of_entity: String = "Entity", speed_of_entity: float = 200.0, hp_of_entity: int = 20):
    print("объект создан")
    _name=_name_of_entity
    hp = hp_of_entity
    speed=speed_of_entity
    max_hp=hp


Если вам нужно, чтобы наследуемые объекты имели все параметры базового, то предлагаю следующий вариант:
Наследование объектов

Создаем базовую сцену с желаемой структурой, от которого будут наследоваться.




Задаем параметры.

Параметры, которые будут меняться у наследуемых объектов, задаем через export (Export Properties).
@export var _name: String = "Entity"
@export var _speed: float = 200
@export var _max_health: int = 100

var _health: int


Не забываем про объекты сцены.
@onready var sprite: Panel = $Sprite
@onready var collision: CollisionShape2D = $Collision

@onready var name_label: Label = $Name
@onready var health_label: Label = $Health


Пишем логику инициализации сцены.

func _ready() -> void:
    self._health = self._max_health
    self.name_label.text = self._name
    self.health_label.text = "HP: %d" % self._health

    # Для наглядности вывожу данные о сцене
    print("Сцена `%s` добавлена в дерево" % self._name)
    print("- Speed: %d" % self._speed)
    print("- HP: %d\n" % self._health)

Полный код (entity.gd):
class_name Entity extends CharacterBody2D

@export var _name: String = "Entity"
@export var _speed: float = 200
@export var _max_health: int = 100

var _health: int

@onready var sprite: Panel = $Sprite
@onready var collision: CollisionShape2D = $Collision

@onready var name_label: Label = $Name
@onready var health_label: Label = $Health

func _ready() -> void:
    self._health = self._max_health
    self.name_label.text = self._name
    self.health_label.text = "HP: %d" % self._health
    
    print("Сцена `%s` добавлена в дерево" % self._name)
    print("- Speed: %d" % self._speed)
    print("- HP: %d\n" % self._health)


Теперь, когда нам нужно создать наследуемую сцену, делаем это через Instantiate Child Scene (иконка цепи).


Выбираем базовую сцену, от которой наследуемся.


Если нужно изменить параметры какого-либо объекта сцены, выбираем нужный и нажимаем на Make Unique.

Например, если нужно изменить размер коллизии, то выбираем объект CollisionShape2D.

Нажимаем на стрелку вниз и из выпадающего списка выбираем Make Unique.

Итог
Результат.

Вывод:
Сцена `Entity` добавлена в дерево
- Speed: 200
- HP: 100

Сцена `Player` добавлена в дерево
- Speed: 500
- HP: 200

Сцена `Enemy` добавлена в дерево
- Speed: 100
- HP: 50

Дерево сцены:
 ┖╴Playground
    ┠╴Entity
    ┃  ┠╴Collision
    ┃  ┠╴Sprite
    ┃  ┠╴Health
    ┃  ┖╴Name
    ┠╴Player
    ┃  ┠╴Collision
    ┃  ┠╴Sprite
    ┃  ┠╴Health
    ┃  ┖╴Name
    ┖╴Enemy
       ┠╴Collision
       ┠╴Sprite
       ┠╴Health
       ┖╴Name


Как по мне, такой подход к созданию экземпляров сцены подходит для быстрого создания статических объектов. Например, если игра в жанре "выживание", таким объектом будет предмет, который может подобрать игрок (например, камень, палка и т.д.).
Советую вам ознакомиться с системой компонентов (ссылка на статью)

Спасибо, с наследованием уже разобрался, суть моей изначальной идеи была использовать именно _init(), но это оказалось довольно непрактично для такой задачи (создавать объект класса, а после добавлять его в дерево). Моя новая реализация заключается в добавлении сцены, а уже привязанный к ней скрипт и является объектом. т.е. обратное от изначального. Спасибо за ёмкий ответ и ссылку на систему компонентов, она во многом действительно лучше, особенно если будет крупный проект с различного рода взаимодействиями.
